# Как установить libcurl в Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition?

Tags: curl, visual-studio, c++

Расскажите, пожалуйста, поподробней как установить libcurl в Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

Answer (score 2):

1. Скачать файл libcurl-7.18.0-win32-msvc.zip c сайта cURL;
2. Распаковать
3. Подключить к проекту файл curl.lib
4. Положить в какой-нибудь известный системе каталог файл curl.dll
5. Скомпилировать проект и запустить

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-devel-msvc вот это я как понял уже скомпилированные длл
curllib.dll я кидал в system32
curllib.lib в папку Lib Вижуала
но при запуске

#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(void)
{
CURL *curl;//Объект CURL
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
return 0;
}

но при запуске откомпелированного прилодения он выдал ошибку
"Порядковый номер 55 не найден в библиотеке DD zlib.dl"

Comment: А можно посмотреть что это за порядковый номер 55? Для этого нужно взять утилиты Dependency Viewer (или Walker - не помню). Да и система 32 бита или 64 ?